# How to use relative path to Resources folder in C# Window Form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to play sound when the window form loaded,

```
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer( @"song.mp3" );
sound.Play();
```

When distributing this project to others, I can't use absolute path. So how can I use relative path in this case? Where the `song.mp3` is located in `"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Game\Resources\song.mp3"`?

Thanks,

Comment: How did it end up there?  Your installer should never create folders on the desktop.  Use Application.StartupPath to get the path to the .exe, your .mp3 should not be far from that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a resources bundle and store it in the bundle, and just reference the sound file within the bundle.

IE: when creating a winforms project by default, you'll see a Resources.resx file in the Properties folder. Add a resource there, and then reference it from code:

```
Properties.Resources.String1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what's resources bundle, could you briefly explain how to create that?

Comment: If you right click on your project, and go to properties. Than click the tab for "Resources". Then add your resources that you want to use in your application. Then reference them as you would Properties.Resources.etc...