# Loading image from code using relative path in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, image, relative-path

I have an `Image` in my application and I have a picture in my WinForms.

```
public static string Correct_Icons = @"C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileShareMgmt\FileShareMgmt\Resources\Correct.png";
public static string warning_Icon = @"C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FileShareMgmt\FileShareMgmt\Resources\Warning.png";


cell.Value = Image.FromFile("Resources/warning_Icon);
```

But I just want to use a *relative path* and not the full path like above.

For example something like this:

```
public static string Correct_Icons  = "\Resources\Correct.png";
```

and cont.
..../
not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you embed the icons within your assembly?

Comment: Check this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608684/how-to-use-relative-path-to-resources-folder-in-c-window-form-application

Comment: I agree with Jon. You should embed images, especially icons. The only reason not to do this is if you wanted to dynamically modify the image.

Comment: i am in the testing phases.. so i was not keen in putting images and removing them.. but i think in the end i will.. thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For my program, `Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` returns
`C:\code\test\Junk\bin\Debug`.

```
cell.Value = Image.FromFile(
  Path.Combine (
     Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
     "Resources/warning_Icon"));
```

Of course, usually you would embed the resources in your assembly unless you want to change them without a recompile.

Answer (score 2):

> My issue was solved after this solution:
>
> ```
> string[] s = { "\\bin" };
> string path = Application.StartupPath.Split(s, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "\\Images\\On24.png";
> ```