# how to give relative path

Tags: c#, file-io, uri

I have a image in the current project, to access it, I use the absolute path, like
`myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"F:\jcnu\DisplayDemo1_c#_CircleBased\Display1\120px-Arrow_Blue_Right_001.png");`

Now I want to give the relative path so that I can move this application to any other path.

I can place the image to any sub-folder of the project so consider this as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this - AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory in your Uri - it points on folder where is application installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511816/loading-image-from-relative-path-in-windows-forms