# C#: FileNotFoundException when loading images from resource

Tags: c#, image, resources, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to load in a bunch of images from my resource file but I am getting the FileNotFoundException for some reason. the Image names are like so:
"image01.png", "image02.png", ... , "image10.png", image11.png"

In the end I want to be able to display all of the images on the screen.

Here is what I have:

```
  String imgName;
        int row = 0, col = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            //get the name of the current image
            if (i < 10)
                imgName = "image0" + i + ".png";
            else
                imgName = "image" + i + ".png";

            Image img = null;
            try { 
                img = Image.FromFile(imgName);//read the image from the resource file
            }
                catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("ERROR!!!" + e); }
}
```

Here is a sample error output that I am getting:

```
ERROR!!!System.IO.FileNotFoundException: tile01.png
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
```

Screenshot:
[image: updated code]

I have also fixed a type on line 56 from: "PictureForm.PuzzleForm." to "PicturePuzzle." but still no luck.

Comment: What is your "resource file", where is it stored, and where is your code executing from in relation to that resource file?

Comment: Embedded resource files are built into the output assembly.  Where in this code do you think you're telling the computer to look for the files in the assembly?  You appear to be trying to load them from the filesystem.

Comment: @adv12: It doesn't really look like he's trying to load an embedded resource, but rather load .png files from disk.

Comment: My resource file is a file in my project file. The path is like so: C:\Users\me\blah\Project\MyImageProject\Resources

Comment: Isn't it similar like java, where your project can have a res folder where you can put your images in it and just read it from there?

Comment: @bobdylan: You can either embed your images in a binary file (commonly your .exe) by setting the property Build Action to Embedded Resource, or leave them as separate files by setting Build Action to Content.  If you leave as content, set Copy to Output Directory to True.

Comment: The images? No. Sorry I'm new to C# so I am a bit confused with this whole assembly thing. I thought if I created a folder within my project, or added them to the resources folder, then I could just access them just by specifying the image name.

Comment: @bobdylan: You can, but you need to make sure Copy to Output Directory is set to True.  I updated my answer to fully explain that.

Comment: @EricJ How do I do that? I don't know what or where that is.

Comment: @bobdylan: Added a screenshot from Visual Studio to my answer.

Comment: If you're using a .resx file, you would access the file at `<ProjectNamespace>.Properties.Resources.<Filename>`

Comment: So if your project namespace is `Bob.Dylan`, and your file name is `image1.jpg`, you would access it by `Bod.Dylan.Properties.Resources.image1.jpg`

Comment: @BrianWarshaw thanks. How could I do that if I had a bunch of images though? Would I have to type that out 'n' amount of times or could I use a loop for it somehow?

Comment: The question ultimately is: what are you trying to do with these images? If you need to iterate through them and do some batch activity, then embedding them may not be the best thing to do anyhow.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw sorry I should have said that from the beginning: I am trying load/read in a bunch of images and display them all together on the screen. So for example if I had 16 images, I would want to load all of them in and display in 4 columns and 4 rows (ie image 1 would be at (0, 0), image 2 would be at (1, 0)...etc)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. In the end I was too incompetent to figure it out the way you guys were showing me, but I found a solution that helps me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511816/loading-image-from-relative-path-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying a path to load the file from.  They will be loaded from where the assembly is running.

Note that Image.FromFile does not load an embedded resource, but rather the .png from disk.  I assume this is what you intend.

Check the properties for the images in Visual Studio and ensure that Copy to Output Directory is Copy if Newer or Copy Always.  Here's a screenshot (in my case it's a cursor resource, but same idea for an image).

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you have embedded your images in your EXE or another file, you can use code similar to

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg");
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf17tthe(v=vs.90).aspx))

**NOTE**

You can either embed your images in a binary file (commonly your .exe) by setting the property Build Action to Embedded Resource, or leave them as separate files by setting Build Action to Content.  If you leave as content, set Copy to Output Directory to True.

Comment: Ignore my prior comment--I can see from your comment on the OP that you are interpreting his post to suggest he *wants* the files local. Apologies.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: I updated my answer to account for both possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing that but I am getting an error for that last line. The error is : "...does not contain a defintion for 'picturebox1' and no extension method for 'picturebox1' accepting a first argument type of MyProject.MyClass' could be found"

Comment: Could it be because my 2nd to last line is like this: System.IO.Stream file =
                    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName." + imgName);

Comment: You need to drop in the actual name of your assembly (e.g. MyProject) and the actual name of your image file.  "AssemblyName" is a placeholder for the name of your program.

Comment: I have fixed the Copy to Output for all of them now, and I have changed the Assmeble name to: "MyProject.MyClass." but I am still getting the previous error. I will take a screenshot and add it above.

Comment: You have your Build Action set to None in the screenshot.  Should be Content.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code to say where the files are located so it's defaulting to somewhere the files aren't.  If the files sit in the same location as your exe then try something like 
imgNmae = "./image0" + i + ".png";

adjusting the relative path to account for where the files actually sit.

Comment: If his files are in the same location as his .exe, then there is no need to add the `./` portion of the path. It's already looking there.