# How do i find file paths in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, in my program i have a folder called resources, this stores images which i load in the program. Currently i have the path hard-coded in but my friends now want to use the program, is there any way to get the file path to this folder no matter which computer it's on? surely there must be a way.

The current file path is:

`H:\Desktop\Solutions\Home\PokeSheet\PokeSheet\Resources`

I want it to be able to find the `H:\Desktop\Solutions\Home` part on its own as that is the part that will change each time

Comment: Look to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511816/loading-image-from-relative-path-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use `Directory` class:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Or:

```
// As suggested by Martin Bäckström
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

These will return the directory where program is executed. You need only to concat `Resources` string to obtained path.

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` changed if you open a `FileDialog`. To solve this you need to do this:

```
yourDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

Anyway, to use `Resources` the best way is:

```
Resource.YourResource;
```

Where `Resource` is the name of you resource file/class.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); change if you opens a file dialog.

Comment: @MartinBäckström In this case you need to set `RestoreDirectory` to `true` for the `FileDialog`. Good point.

Comment: It must be better to use something that doesnt change, e.g. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: Yes. This is the better solution for desktop applications. I will add also your solution to my answer. +1 on your comments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find application startup path in `StartupPath` static variable:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
```