# Load image from relative path in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, image, relative-path

I have a picture box in my application, I'm not really sure how to set the relative path.
My directory structure is

```
components
    icons
     -- warning.png
    myCustomBox.cs
```

So I'm trying to set the image from myCustomBox.cs

```
imageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\mike\source\repos\Management\components\icons\warning.png");
```

I want the relative path like

```
imageBox.Image = Image.FromFile("/icons/warning.png");
```

Could anyone please help me out?

I did find an answer to the question tried it out but no luck throws the same "file not found" error
[Loading image from relative path in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511816/loading-image-from-relative-path-in-windows-forms)

Below is my code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Management
{
    public partial class myCustomBox: Form
    {
        public myCustomBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void showIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imageBox.Image = Image.FromFile("/icons/warning.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tried it out but no luck` Post *that* code. If it doesn't work for you there must be a simple mistake somewhere but no one can guess what or where without seeing the actual code.

Comment: I've added in the code.

Comment: 1) The posted code doesn't show any attempt to `Path.Combine` like in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511874/5538420). 2) A path starting with `"/"` (or, rather, `"\"` in Windows) is not a relative path, but an absolute path rooted under the drive of the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path is in relation the location where the application is running from, normally wherever your .exe file is.

In Visual Studio, select the image within your project and change the "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy if newer". Then when you build your project the it'll copy the image into you bin folder for you.

Comment: I'm currently running the project in debug mode.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.