# How to point to a file stored in project folder? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filereference

At the moment I'm pointing to a file on my machine, but I'm wondering how I would point the string to a folder I created within the project. For example the path to the folder in visual studio is,

```
C:\Users\Drian Darley\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\KinectBVversion1\KinectKickboxingBVversion1\Gesture\jabtwo.xml
```

I have heard of pack URI's, would that suit in this situation or how would I set one up?

This is how it is pointing to the file at present, which is not ideal as it has to point to a file stored locally on the machine.

```
private string gesturefile =
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\GesturePak\\wave.xml";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335618/file-path-for-project-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this

```
string gesturefile= Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"GesturePak\wave.xml");
```

Examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/path

or

Use `Path.GetFullPath`

Example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

Comment: But you should keep in mind that the value of the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property may change during the runtime of the application.

Comment: the following worked for me, `private string gesturefile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Gesture\wave.xml");`

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want to store files separately you need to set their `Build Action` to `Resource` (in the Properties window in Visual Studio) and access them by a Pack URI:

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GesturePAK/wave.xml");
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
```

Now you can access the content of the XML file by `resourceStream`. For example reading the file content into a string could be done like this:

```
string content;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: The code is meant to be executed in a method. Perhaps in the constructor of your MainWindow class.

Comment: okay, then how do I convert this `resource stream` back to a string? As it requires a string type.

Comment: You mean you want to read the content of the resource (XML) file? See my edit please.

Comment: ,no I just need a string variable to point to the file, I have an api that does the reading.Is there a way to point a string variable to the file path?

Comment: Do you understand what I mean? the file is read by the api so I just need to have a string variable that points to the folder in my project called "Gesture".If I use your above solution the file will be parsed into this variable which doesn't suit.

Comment: Of course I understand that. And you could have mentioned this fact before, ideally in your question. When that API requires a file name, I'm pretty sure that it wants to read a regular file from your local file system. This can't be done with a pack URI, which references a file resource inside your application's assembly.

Comment: okay, the gesture file is being added to a list wthin the program like this ` Gesture g1 = new Gesture(gesturefile);

            // Add it to a gestures collection
            List<Gesture> gestures = new List<Gesture>();
            gestures.Add(g1);`

Answer (score 1):

for example, if you create a folder called "Images" within your project, then you can point like:

```
string address="Images/dukenukem.jpg";
```

Comment: Not without either making the file a resource and using a pack URI or taking care that VS copies the Images folder to the current project's output directory.