# How can i call a textfile(included the project) and read from it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files

I'm trying to create a smmall Website for some Document to fill them out. It's a lot standard Information and i created an included textfile to read from. My problem is, that i don't know how to read from it, if i move the project somewhere else. Something like that maybe:

```
String path = "http://localhost:52179/source.txt";
        string[] myLines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Where is source.txt actually located on your system/server? Use that path.

Comment: You need to get the relative path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335618/file-path-for-project-files

Comment: You cannot use an url like that to read the file from server code. You need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It is not clear if you are running the two lines above from the server code-behind inside one of your aspx pages or if you are trying to read that file from a client machine using a browser or some sort of client software. Could you explain?

Comment: It is located in the Website directory, where my all sources(html, css etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the help, from everyody. It is in this case not possible, because i have to declare different values, to different keys, so i cannot put it in a for/foreach loop. Altough i could copy this file to the server and read from it, with the same Method i wrote in the question.